# np.sum returns a different answer after reordering a np.float32 array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1024^3 np.float32 array, call it `a`.  The problem is when I reorder the array, for instance `b=a[::-1]`, then `np.sum(a)` is not the same as `np.sum(b)`.  In my case, `np.sum(a) = -0.018108368` and `np.sum(b) = -0.014070511`.  I actually need to do some other operations on `a` to shift the elements around, so after those steps the difference between the summations are even larger (factor of 2 level).  Is this caused by using `np.float32`, so that errors accumulate for such large arrays?

The problem can be reproduced by generating random smaller arrays, e.g. 500^3.

Comment: Yes, and no. Due to floating point precision, `sum` is not associative, there will be slight errors when you shuffle your array and sum. The errors are more pronounce when you use less precision, e.g. `float64` compared to `float32`. For `float32`, the errors is visible even 1000 numbers.